# get next open tcp port in windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, tcp

How is it possible to get next open tcp port on windows
I've searched the web and i came across TcpPortsGatherer written in Qt...
the only problem is that its not available in my current Qt version or it should be used as a plugin 
so I'm looking for a way to use [TcpPortsGatherer Class](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-extending/utils-tcpportsgatherer.html) 
or just use native windows libraries if any is available

Update :

I've Used Sebastian's approach like below to bind the found port to an external binary that I run but it always assign the port 1025 to the executable , how can i fix this ?

```
QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
qint16 port = 1025;
while(!socket->bind(port, QAbstractSocket::DontShareAddress))
  port++;
socket->close();
socket->deleteLater();
```

Comment: If port 1025 is unused it will use this port. just set up port to start from your desired port. I use 1024+ to stay out of privileged ports. You could alwas use a ```QList<qint16>``` if you want to use a given list of ports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try using `QTcpSocket::bind()`. It will return a bool(true) if port open was successfull.

```
QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
qint16 port = 1025;
while(!socket->bind(port, QAbstractSocket::DontShareAddress))
{
  port++;
}
```

socket is now bound to port.

Answer (score 3):

Just specify port zero and bind. The system  will give you the next available port. No loop required.